# problem in showing 3 images in a row

Tags: php

hey guys , i know this is a stupid question  but i hanged in solving it

i wrote a block of php code to show images from mysql

```
    echo "<table><tr> ";

    while($cat = $db->sql_fetchrow($catinfo)) {
        echo '
        <td>
        <ul id="three-col" class="press">   
        <li>
    <div class="post-content">
    <a class="zoom1" href="'.$galsettings[setImgDir].'/'.$cat[galCatLocation].'/'.$cat[galCatImg].'">
    <img src="'.$galsettings[setImgDir].'/'.$cat[galCatLocation].'/'.$cat[galCatImg].'" alt="artistry (via powerbooktrance)" />
    </a>
    </div>';

    for ($i=0; $i>2; $i++) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    }

echo "</li></ul></td></tr></table>";
```

but with this code everything goes wrong and it doesnt break after each 3 images in row

i even used

```
if ($i>2) {
    echo "</td></tr><tr>";
}
```

but as u know it only breaks the tr after  image number 3  not every row

im really sorry for my foolish question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<table><tr> ";

$counter = 0;

while($cat = $db->sql_fetchrow($catinfo)) {

    $counter++;

    echo '
    <td>
    <ul id="three-col" class="press">   
    <li>
    <div class="post-content">
    <a class="zoom1" href="'.$galsettings[setImgDir].'/'.$cat[galCatLocation].'/'.$cat[galCatImg].'">
    <img src="'.$galsettings[setImgDir].'/'.$cat[galCatLocation].'/'.$cat[galCatImg].'" alt="artistry (via powerbooktrance)" />
    </a>
    </div>
    ';

    if ( $counter == 3 ) {

        echo '</tr><tr>';

        $counter = 0;
    }

}

echo "</li></ul></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: yeah, you probably want to move `</li></ul></td>` right after the `</div>`

Comment: that was really smart my friend , love u

Comment: hey bud , i got a new problem  , look at here :
http://mahlaghabonbon.com/

in IE doesnt show 3images in row

Answer (score 1):

First off, the

```
  for ($i=0; $i>2; $i++) {
```

should probably be

```
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {
```

There may be additional logic issues (looking)...

Indeed the logic seems utterly flawed, for ex. there doesn't appear to be anything which detects the the third image etc...

==> I suggest you try the snippet from tambler's answer.  No point in trying and fix this one... but if you must:

- the  `for ($i=0; $i>2; $i++) {` loop is unnecessary.  Even when fixed to $i < 2 (or 3...) this doesn't do anything useful.
- with each new image you output a `<td>`, this needs to be closed with a `</td>`
- there need to be a counter (the $i) you hint at in your snippet isn't valid
- the counter is to be systematically incremented with each image
- a test is to be added towards the end of the loop:
       If counter >= 3  (or 2, if you make it 0-based)
           reset counter;
           emit  ""
- Also the `<ul>` and `<li>` and their respective closing tags are misplaced.

Comment: i respect ur answer that was something , but bro that was not so clear for beginers like me

Answer (score 0):

Where's you're `</td>` tag?

All your TDs have to be inside the TRs.  You have to close the UL and TD before your TR.